# Select only from one table in another schema

Tags: sql-server

I have question about schemas and permissions in MS SQL.
We have 2 schemas DBO and PAD and an user PadUser who has permission only to PAD schema (DENY for Select in DBO schema)
I want to create view in PAD schema which will select data from one table in DBO schema.
Is there any possibility to retrieve data from this view ?

I tried to add GRANT permission for a PadUser to this table in DBO schema but it didn't work. It seams that DENY on Select in DBO schema is stronger.

Any suggestions how to configure this type of access (Select data only from one table in DBO schema) ?

Comment: `DENY` > `GRANT`. If you have explicitly denied the user access, they can't access it.

Comment: I've not done this: Could you create a synonym for the table and grant permissions explicitly to it?  I'm not sure if it would work but it should be pretty easy to setup/test

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override the DENY you have to suppress permissions checking with [ownership chains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-ownership-chains-and-context-switching?view=sql-server-ver15).  If DBO owns the PAD schema you can simply create a view in PAD that joins the tables, and DBO's ownership of the view and the tables will suppress permissions checks on the tables.

If PadUser owns the schema PAD then you can't safely put dbo-owned objects in that schema, and you must create the dbo-owned view in another schema.  And not the dbo schema because of the DENY.

Note it would be simpler if PadUser simply lacked any permissions in DBO, then you could selectively grant the permissions required.

Comment: Just to clarify.
We have 2 schemas DBO and PAD. 
User PadUser who has Select DENY on DBO schema but he's own PAD schema
And this PadUser needs to have access to one table from DBO schema.

Comment: see updated answer.